# Jquery-ui resizable plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

what on earth am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Draggable crop</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.image_outline').resizable();
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .image_outline {
                border: dashed 1px #000;
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="image_outline"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dAHt8/

Why is the resizeable plugin not making the `div` resizeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine once you add the right CSS link:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dAHt8/3/)**.

For that jsFiddle I linked to the hosted jQuery UI CSS at: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css